# How to change the SID of webforms to increment from a new starting number

Tags: 7, webforms

We launched a new website that uses webforms but need to make sure our webforms are using an SID for results larger than the last number used on the old site.

Please note that I am not referring to the serial for the webform submission but Drupal's SID.

For example, on the new site, the first submission ID was 1. I need it to be 10000.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Drupal 7 site:

1. Edit the webform.
2. Go to the "Form settings" subtab of the Webform
   tab.
3. Scroll down and expand the Advanced Settings section. 
   There's an exposed field for the Next submission number.

[image: modifying the advanced settings for the form]

---

If it's a Drupal 8 site:

1. Edit the webform.
2. Go to the "settings" subtab of the Webform
3. Scroll down and expand the Submission Settings section. 
   There's an exposed field for the Next submission number.

[image: modifying the advanced settings for the form]

Comment: Thank you but this only defines the next serial. Not the submission ID.

Comment: You'll want to directly edit database value.  Checkout https://www.drupal.org/node/337613

Comment: In most cases both the SD and serialized value are in sync if only one form exists on the site.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment with the link was the answer I needed.

Comment: After updating the sid in the database, did you also reset webform submission numbers for your use case, or were submissions being tracked by the unique SIDs? It'd be helpful to share for others looking to migrate forms and keep a method for indexing.

Comment: No, I had already set the webform submission serial where I needed it to be. This was done in order to make sure that all SID's and Serials were unique from any submission on our old site.